# How to request data from mongodb (mongoose) from subdocument within the interval "from" and "to"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to return data that matches the range, and that's it. When requested, I will be returned an entire document that meets the conditions.

Do not know how to properly compose a query so that the database returns a ready data rage, without the need to filter after response on the server side.

**Document structure:**

```
{
    symbol: "test",
    data: [{
            timestamp: 1,
            value: 10,
        },
        {
            timestamp: 2,
            value: 20,
        },
        {
            timestamp: 3,
            value: 30,
        },
        {
            timestamp: 4,
            value: 40,
        },
    ]
}
```

**My request:**

```
function request(symbol, from, to) {
    return model.findOne({
        symbol,
        data: {
            $elemMatch: {
                timestamp: {
                    $gte: from,
                    $lt: to
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(res => res.data)
}

request('test', 2, 3)
```

Got response as full document structure. Using `res.data.filter` bad approach, because it has a big performance impact. Only the required data needs to be returned.

**Example response as needed:**

```
{
    symbol: "test",
    data: [
        {
            timestamp: 2,
            value: 20,
        },
        {
           timestamp: 3,
            value: 30,
        },
      
    ]
}

// or better 

[
 {
            timestamp: 2,
            value: 20,
        },
        {
           timestamp: 3,
            value: 30,
        },
]
```

Thanks for the advice. Tried different variants from stackoverflow, nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

don't need the elementMatch function , you can query from subdocument as :

```
function request(symbol, from, to) {
    return model.findOne({
            symbol : symbol,
            'data.timestamp' : { $gte: from, $lt: to }
        }
    }).then(res => res.data)
}
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Tnx, for reply. This one response full length of array.